# MySQL query data into a PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get a value from a MySQL database and put it into a PHP variable.

I tried this:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT userid FROM ao_user " . 
  "WHERE username = '{$this->_username}' " . 
  "AND password = '{$this->_password}' AND display = '{$this->_display}'");
```

The code says invalid username/password.

Here is the user login code:

```
<?php
  $username = "Nynex71";
  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "test") or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT display FROM ao_user " . 
    "WHERE username = '{$username}'") or die(msyql_error());
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  echo $row['display'];
?>
```

and

```
public function getDisplay()
  {
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "test") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT display FROM ao_user " . 
      "WHERE username = '{$this->_username}'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $this->_display = $row['display'];
    $_SESSION['display'] = $this->_display;
  }
```

The program does not put any words into the PHP variable.  What am I doing wrong and how do you do this?

Comment: The below answer is correct. However my piece of advise is if you are just starting out learning PHP & MySQL. Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) As mysql_* are depreciated, and therefore you might as well forget that they exist!

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_query` returns a result handle, not the value you selected. you have to first fetch a row, then retrieve the value from that row:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ...") or die(msyql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['userid'];
```

Comment: to get all answer rows (and not only the first one) put the "$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)" part into a loop like "while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { echo $row['userid']; }"